# How to find monotone answer pattern

Tags: r

I'm trying to find a way to identify monotone answer patterns of participants in my experiment. For example if someone answered the first Option, coded as "1" in all of the first 10 Questions. I tried to do it with the standard deviation which has to be zero if there is no variance in the answers, but i wasn't successful so far. Here is my attempt:

```
m.check <- function(data,startrow, endrow){
   out <- ifelse(sapply(data, startrow:endrow,sd) ==0,T, F)
   return(out)
}
data$mono <- m.check(as.numeric(data,1,10))
```

Comment: Perhaps something like this? It checks to see if any runs are the same length as the vector itself and will return `TRUE` if it is. `monotone <- function(x)any(rle(x)$lengths == length(x))`.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: an alternative approach could be `all(x == x[1])` in the function